# How to write the response to the text file

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net

I am trying to log the request response from the service into a text file. I am using log4net to log the response to a text file but it is logging only the request but not the response.
How can I do this?

```
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

        if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
        {
        SaveResponseToLog("AfterReceiveReply" +"\n##### VisService SOAP Response #####\n");
        string filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Daimler AG\\Vis@\\" + "log.txt";
        System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer = null;
        MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message replyCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            writer = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs);
            replyCopy.WriteMessage(writer);

            MessageBox.Show("AfterReceiveReply" + writer.ToString());
            writer.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Something went wrong while writing the response
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
        }
  }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
        {
            string visServiceSOAPRequest = request.ToString();
            log.Error("Error:VisService SOAP Request >>>");
            log.Error(visServiceSOAPRequest);
            //For displaying the message in the mail confirmation box
            SaveResponseToLog("BeforeSendRequest" + "\nVisService SOAP Request >>>\n" + visServiceSOAPRequest);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void SaveResponseToLog(string message)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = null;
        //StreamReader rd = null;
        string filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\My App\\Application\\" + "log.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))               
            {

                 fs.Flush();
                 fs.Close();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {                    
                    writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(filename);
                    writer.Write(message);  
                    writer.Flush();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Wenn das loggen nicht funktioniert, kann der Fehler ja nicht geloggt werden..
            log.Error("Error saving the message in the log.txt file: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You could wrap `fs` and `writer` in a `using` block and be rid of the need for your `finally`, just by the way. You'd also be cleaning up the file, which sounds important for an app like this.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen - Ok I will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Following code just work for me. Decorate your service implementation by attribute [MyServiceBehavior]

Requests can be seen in AfterReceiveRequest method.

Responses can be seen in BeforeSendReply method.

```
    public class MyServiceBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher chDisp in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher epDisp in chDisp.Endpoints)
                {
                    epDisp.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new Inspector());
                    foreach (DispatchOperation op in epDisp.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
                        op.ParameterInspectors.Add(new Inspector());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Inspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IParameterInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest called.");
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply called.");
        }

        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
              "IParameterInspector.AfterCall called for {0} with return value {1}.",
              operationName,
              returnValue.ToString()
            );
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IParameterInspector.BeforeCall called for {0}.", operationName);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure about this example. I have a extended class for the original service reference class.

Comment: This is giving me an error when i start the application after doing this.